# Spark Scala Dataframes: Filter records which returns false for a function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

```
dataFrame.select(columnName).filter(myFunction(_));
```

I need to filter out only those records which returns true for "myFunction";
myFunction accepts the column value for each records, and does some analysis on the value and returns true or false.

What I want to achieve is to filter out values which cannot be cast to numeric data (say double). I have a column which contains mostly numeric data and a few string data. I want to filter out those values which cannot be cast to double.

Comment: And what exactly is not working with the code you're using? What is your actual question?

Comment: you'll need to map on your function. filter will just take the record where the condition returned by myFunction is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *filter out values which cannot be cast to numeric data* then cast and drop NULLs:

```
val df = sc.parallelize((1L, "0.213") :: (2L, "foo") :: (3L, "4.0") :: Nil)
  .toDF("k", "v")

df.withColumn("v", $"v".cast("double")).na.drop(Seq("v"))
```

If you want to use a custom function you'll have to convert data to RDD:

```
df.rdd.filter(r => ???)
```

of use UDF:

```
df.where(udf(myFunction _)(columnName))
```